# Request.get blocked coming from Atom only

Tags: python, django, http, atom-editor, firewall

I am writing a django app with communcitaion to external python scripts in other software. As I am currently checking all basi requirements and their functionality, I am working with the standard django sql lite testserver.

While testing, I am facing a weird firewall/ site blocking issue.

A simple request.get() is working fine from windows cmd, receiving my json response.
Opening the page in any browser from any computer within my company network works as well.

However, when simply launching the request from atom on the local host pc, it fails with 403 - response.content.decode() showing the site is receiving a prompt due to being uncategorized and I would have to click to "continue browsing for work related purposes".

As this is only happening from within atom - any ideas how to prevent this?

What I tried so far:

- Adding headers (not change)
- launching a subprocess calling cmd with the command (works, but sort of failing the purpose of the script)
  Goal is to simply retrieve a json response from a view so I can transfer the information to my program.

Thanks a lot

Update: this is down to atom. Working in eclipse and Visual Studio as expected. My solution for now is using Eclipse then, but it would be great to get it working inside atom, as this is more or less a collection of scripts working inside other programms python APIs.

Thomas

Comment: minor uddate comment:
tested with idle: working
tested a clone on a pc without forcepoint set up; working
this issue is down to how the script package handles html requests (probably opening a browser in the background...) -> will check with eclipse and other run packages for atom.

Comment: Further testing results.. Testing python run package is getting blocked, too.